# Zope (ZPT) overlapping tags

Tags: html, zope, template-tal, zpt, template-metal

I try to create an open `div` tag condition and close a `div` tag in another condition with TAL in a Zope Page Template but I'm not allowed to overlap tags.

Here is my code :

```
<div id="notaccordion">                                                                                      
    <tal:x repeat="item python:range(26)">                                                                                                                         
        <tal:x define="global block_name python:current.values()[0]['block_name']">         

            <tal:x condition="python:isDone">                                                                               
                </div>                                                                                  
            </tal:x>    

            <tal:x condition="python:not isDone">                                                                                     
                <tal:x replace="python:block_name">                                                                                                                                             
                </tal:x>                                                                                                       
                <div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
            </tal:x>  

        </tal:x>                                                                     
     </tal:x>                                                                                                                              
 </div>
```

The important part is:

```
            <tal:x condition="python:isDone">                                                                               
                </div>                                                                                  
            </tal:x>
```

And here is the error.

```
Compilation failed
zope.tal.taldefs.TALError: TAL attributes on <tal:x> require explicit </tal:x>
```

I tried with a Python script but it didn't work either.

```
<div id="notaccordion">                                                                                      
    <tal:x repeat="item python:range(26)">                                                                                                                         
        <tal:x define="global block_name python:current.values()[0]['block_name']">         

            <tal:x condition="python:isDone">                                                                               
                <tal:x content="python:context[close_div]()">
                </tal:x>                                                                                           
            </tal:x>    

            <tal:x condition="python:not isDone">
                <tal:x replace="python:block_name">                                                                                                                                                         
                </tal:x>                                                                                                       
                <tal:x content="python:context[open_div]()">
                </tal:x>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
            </tal:x>  

        </tal:x>                                                                     
    </tal:x>                                                                                                                              
</div>
```

With `close_div` script:

```
print '</div>'
return printed
```

It returns `&lt;/div&gt;` instead of `</div>`

If you wonder why I'm doing it. I have a tree structure that I need to display. Since I (think I) can't do it recursively, I try to emulate it using a LIFO list. And `current` is my current node.

I try to achieve this (node is dict of dict... used as a tree) :

```
lifo = list()
lifo.append([node, False])

while lifo:
    current, isDone = lifo[-1]
    block = current.keys()[0]
    if isDone:
        print '</div>'
        lifo.pop()
    else:
        lifo[-1][1] = True
        print '<div>'
        print block
        children = current[block].get('children', {})
        if children:
            for childBlock, childValue in children.items():
                lifo.append([{childBlock:childValue}, False])
```

Any help or suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page templates have to be valid XML, so you cannot just arbitrarily include tags willy nilly. Tree structures are best handled recursively (perhaps with macro snippets):

```xml
<metal:recurse define-macro="list">
  <ul>
    <li tal:repeat="el elements">
      <span tal:content="el/id">element id</span>
      <metal:block tal:condition="el/children"
                   tal:define="elements el/children">
        <div metal:use-macro="template/macros/list" />
      </metal:recurse>
    </li>
  </ul>
</metal:recurse>
```

The Plone navigation portlet, for example, also uses a [separate macro template](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.portlets/blob/master/plone/app/portlets/portlets/navigation_recurse.pt) for each level, calling into itself to render children (`recurse` *is* the same template).

For your specific method using a `open_div` or `close_div` script, you need to [mark the content value as `structure`](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/AdvZPT.html#inserting-structure) to prevent the automatic HTML escaping from taking place:

```xml
<tal:x content="structure python:context[open_div]()">
```

Comment: Great, `structure` keyword made it work just fine. I will probaly use your macro later. Thank you.